# FOSUserBundle: "The file could not be found." error while resetting/changing password

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've encountered a strange error while working with FOSUserBundle. When I try to reset or change a password for user who has filename of uploaded image in his entity I receive an error: "The file could not be found." If image field is null, everything is fine. So I've just workaround this problem by setting photo as null before $form->setData($user) in resetAction and then after form submission and validation I set an old photo value again.

My solution:

```
/**
 * Reset user password.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string  $token
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function resetAction(Request $request, $token)
{
    /** @var $formFactory \FOS\UserBundle\Form\Factory\FactoryInterface */
    $formFactory = $this->get('fos_user.resetting.form.factory');
    /** @var $userManager \FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface */
    $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
    /** @var $dispatcher \Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface */
    $dispatcher = $this->get('event_dispatcher');

    $user = $userManager->findUserByConfirmationToken($token);

    if (null === $user) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException(sprintf('The user with "confirmation token" does not exist for value "%s"', $token));
    }

    $event = new GetResponseUserEvent($user, $request);
    $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_INITIALIZE, $event);

    if (null !== $event->getResponse()) {
        return $event->getResponse();
    }

    $form = $formFactory->createForm();

    //fix error upon form validation: "The file could not be found."
    $photo = $user->getPhoto();
    $user->setPhoto(null);

    $form->setData($user);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $event = new FormEvent($form, $request);
        $dispatcher->dispatch(FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_SUCCESS, $event);

        //set photo name instead of null
        $user->setPhoto($photo);

        $userManager->updateUser($user);

        if (null === $response = $event->getResponse()) {
            $url = $this->generateUrl('fos_user_profile_show');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);
        }

        $dispatcher->dispatch(
            FOSUserEvents::RESETTING_RESET_COMPLETED,
            new FilterUserResponseEvent($user, $request, $response)
        );

        return $response;
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Resetting/reset.html.twig', array(
        'token' => $token,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Fragment of my User entity:

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg", "image/png" })
     */
    private $photo;
```

I don't understand why file validation takes place when I submit form without file upload input. And what is the point of checking all fields of user when you just resetting password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In form workflow submit provide handlerequest to fill all user row, set up your form with required false for your form field

Comment: I've already set it up with required false in RegistrationType form and still have same problem. Should I override change password and resetting forms by marking photo field as required false?

Comment: you are using 'fos_user.resetting.form.factory' not 'fos_user.registration.form.factory' yes probably

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! :) but still I have no idea what is a purpose of validating all user's attributes in resetting password form.